# Adding 3rd party reference and The call stack contains only external code error

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly

I have a project in other solution that named "xxx.Core" and I want to use that assembly in another project as reference.

So I added "xxx.Core" reference to my new console application and when I debug that console application I'm getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I added all references that using from "xxx.Core" in console application.

Any idea to solve that ?

**Problem Solved**

I changed "xxx.Core" Culture from AssemblyProperties. Just I rollback that culture then problem solved.

Comment: You can include the project that  you want to reference as part of your solution (Add existing project), or you can build xxx.Core and copy the .dll to your solution folder (or a sub-folder, e.g 'lib') and add a reference to that

Comment: @havardhu As I said I already did that.

Comment: You did not specify how you added the reference, and I suggested two different ways. What is the full error message from the exception?

Comment: @havardhu there is screenshot. And I tried that 2 ways still i'm getting that ; http://s2.postimg.org/4o2ecuc3t/Untitled.png